# Vlc won't start

Tags: 16.04, vlc

Here's the output I get:

```
$ vlc
VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.2-0-g6259d80)
```

No error message, no nothing.
After forking at least I can see that it crashed:

```
[1]  + 25287 exit 1     vlc
```

Where should I begin investigating? Purging and reinstalling didn't help.

EDIT: I tried purging, reinstalling, deleting configs etc. and no solution to be found on stack exchange/vlc forums/other sites helped. Hence I do not expect here any solution suggestions - I'd be glad if I could see some output from `vlc` telling me `this and that library is missing` or `cannot open some file because it is read-only`.

Comment: How about `cvlc`?

Comment: Nothing changes

Comment: How did you install vlc? And what are you trying to play with it? Did you install 'ubuntu-restricted-extras'? - I use vlc 2.2.2-5 installed from the repositories in 16.04.1 LTS and it works. It prints the same message as yours, when started from a command line, and it works.

Comment: `sudo apt install vlc`

Comment: After a few tries, I got this: `vlc --verbose=3 --file-logging --logfile=log.txt` Edit your question and include the contents of your log.txt file that will be created in your home folder.

Comment: You can also try resetting the configs using `vlc --reset-config` then try again.

Comment: Nah, that doesn't work. Same with `--reset-config`. ```[~] vlc --verbose=3 --file-logging --logfile=log.txt                                                                                                                        
VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.2-0-g6259d80)
vlc: unknown option or missing mandatory argument `--file-logging'
Try `vlc --help' for more information.
```

Comment: Please tag me @parto so that I can receive notifications

Comment: Looks like your VLC is corrupted. Have run out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: @Parto: Definitely looks like it is :-) But usually when programs cause problems there is a way to find out what is going on. With `vlc` it seems to be otherwise

Comment: Try looking for vlc log files - maybe they will explain more on the issue.

Comment: @Parto That's the thing - there don't seem to be any logs available anywhere

Comment: @sudous I understand that for others it "just works". The question is where do I search for any information on why it is not working on my machine

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and VLC (with `sudo apt purge vlc`), and deleting the config folder / files (most likely located in `~/.config/vlc`, you'll need to enable "show hidden files" in the file manager to see that folder, Ctrl + h), and then installing it again ?

Comment: @JonasCz. Yes I have

Comment: Just throwing ideas, but maybe there's a "hanged" VLC process still running on the system. Even if you run `apt-get purge vlc`, the process would still be running. If there were, try killing it then restart or re-install vlc.

Comment: Nope: `$killall -9 vlc` yields `vlc: no process found`

Comment: Try installing the [latest version](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vlc/2.2.4-11). First purge yours, and download, and install the .deb file with `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/file.deb`, and then run `sudo apt-get -f install`.

Comment: @luchonacho Tried that, same result: https://paste.ubuntu.com/23669524/

Comment: since there is not an answer Im moving to MPV
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/swap-vlc-mpv-ubuntu

Comment: @LuGo Have you tried to install Vlc 3? https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/master-daily

Comment: @LuGo , Which version of Ubuntu are you running? In what computer (please specify brand name and model of the computer, graphics card/chip, audio card/chip)?

Comment: I got a very good answer to a question of mine this morning, perhaps you can follow the second instructions to see where vlc gets stuck: https://askubuntu.com/a/928667/49482

Comment: `killall -9 vlc`  This command resolved my "VLC won't start issue". It basically kills all the VLC running processes. I think due to some problem in VLC, it is not able to close the running VLC processes. Although, above command resolved my issue, but If anybody figures out why VLC is not able to kill the running processes in the background after closing the VLC, then please let me know.

Comment: tried to refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132800/ubuntu-18-04-wont-open-video-players#comment2288021_1132823

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I don't know why but using the `vlc-wrapper` instead of `cvlc` or `vlc` running the program as root through `gksudo` helped. As so:

```
gksudo vlc-wrapper
```

also make sure `ffmpeg` and other related packages are installed:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg*
```

Comment: I can't consider running as `root` a solution

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of frustration with unmet dependencies, [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/05/install-vlc-3-0-2-ubuntu-16-04-ppa/) worked:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/vlc-3
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-4
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/meson
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue using `vlc-bin` from apt. The snap version (3.0.6 currently) works for me:

```
sudo snap install vlc
```

Comment: Didn't work for me on Ubuntu 18.10. It claimed to have installed VLC 3.0.6, but it must not have set up links correctly, because an older version still executes when I invoke it from the command line. I ended up having to use the Ubuntu GUI installer to do it.

Comment: @Dan did you completely uninstall / purge vlc before snap installing?

Comment: no.  I tried it on a virgin VM and it worked, thanks.