# Ubuntu 18.04 won't open Video Players

Tags: vlc, video-player, smplayer

Ubuntu just won't open Video Files. I have tried different formats and different players as well. It doesn't even open the player.
When I open vlc and smplayer from gui nothing happens, No Loading.

through terminal when I open vlc:

```
darkseider@DARKPC:~$ vlc
VLC media player 3.0.4 Vetinari (revision 3.0.4-0-gf615db6332)
[000055c87f971570] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[000055c87fa4c840] skins2 interface error: cannot instantiate dialogs provider
[000055c87f9754e0] main playlist: playlist is empty
[000055c87fa4c840] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
```

and opening smplayer gives:

```
darkseider@DARKPC:~$ smplayer
smplayer: error while loading shared libraries: libdouble-conversion.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This is getting really frustrating. Please help me. Thank You!!

Answer (score 2):

Consider to reinstall both players with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall vlc smplayer
```

and also reinstall [the package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libdouble-conversion.so.1) with `libdouble-conversion.so.1` library:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libdouble-conversion1
```

Comment: default vlc is worakble but after I installed some lib** make it doesn't work, it works if using `~$ sudo snap install vlc` or `sudo flatpak install vlc` but cannot adjust the language since there has no language option in menu bar. Using `smplayer` as introduced...